# Почему на super метод records нельзя сослаться

Tags: java, record

Почему на суперметоды `record` нельзя сослаться?
Допустим у меня есть класс:

```
public record Test(String str1,String str2) {
    @Override //Не выдает ошибку
    public String str1() {
        return super.str1(); //Cannot resolve method 'str1' in 'Record'
    }
}
```

На момент написания его конечно нет, но при этом:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test test = new Test("строка1","строка2");
       String str1 = test.str1();
       String str2 = test.str2(); //Оба работают корректно
   }
```

`test.str2()`, `test.str2()` и  `@Override` работают корректно то-есть находят его, но при  `super.str1()`
выдается ошибка `Cannot resolve method 'str1' in 'Record'`

Comment: Только замет что ищет не в `Test` а в `Record` понятия не имею как и почему, хотелось бы узнать как это вообще работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### *Почему на суперметоды `record` нельзя сослаться?*

Коротко, "потому что их нет"(с) Майор Пейн.

Кортежи `record` представляют собой финальные неизменяемые классы-обёртки (data class) для хранения и передачи данных, чтобы заменить привычные POJO классы (бины).

Фактически они неявно наследуются от абстрактного класса [`java.lang.Record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/Record.html), в котором, разумеется, не определены геттеры для компонентов кортежа.
В данном случае имеет место попытка *вызвать* геттер, *отсутствующий* в классе-предке, обращаясь к нему при помощи `super`, о чём и сообщает компилятор.

*Более того, у кортежей не определены даже *стандартные* методы класса `Object`: `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` -- все они являются абстрактными!  Таким образом, для кортежа нельзя также написать что-то вроде `super.hashCode()` или `super.toString().`*

Кроме того, такое переопределение геттера само по себе не слишком хорошо и его можно считать дурнопахнущим кодом (code smell)), так как есть риск *прочитать* значение, которое отличается от *записанного* значения, что также сломает контракт `Record::equals`.

##### *`@Override //Не выдает ошибку`*

Дело в том, что сама аннотация `@Override` была модифицирована для геттеров в кортежах, для чего была изменено её описание в спецификации языка Java: [JLS 9.6.4.4: Annotation Interface :: `@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.4):

> If a method declaration in class or interface Q is annotated with `@Override`, then one of the following three conditions must be true, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - the method overrides from Q a method declared in a supertype of Q (§8.4.8.1, §9.4.1.1)
> - the method is override-equivalent to a public method of Object (§4.3.2, §8.4.2)
> - **Q is a record class (§8.10), and the method is an accessor method for a record component of Q (§8.10.3)**

Также об этом упоминалось в [JEP 395: Records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395):

> - The meaning of the `@Override` annotation was extended to include the case where the annotated method is an explicitly declared accessor method for a record component.

---

Абстрагируясь от полезности переопределения геттера для компонента кортежа, можно сказать, что такая аннотация и переопределение позволят разве что отследить изменение / удаление элемента кортежа и потребовать изменения / удаления соответствующего геттера, о чём также говорится в JLS:

> *The use of `@Override` on the accessor method `int x()` ensures that if the record component `x` is modified or removed, then the corresponding accessor method must be modified or removed too.*

Разумеется, при переопределении нельзя будет использовать ключевое слово `super`, но можно иcпользовать ссылку на текущий компонент кортежа `this.x`, или даже завести *локальную переменную с тем же названием*:

```java
record Roo(int x, int y) {
    @Override
    public int x() {
        return Math.abs(this.x);
    }

    @Override
    public int y() {
        int y = 5;
        return y * this.y;  // за такое могут казнить на code review
    }

}
```

Comment: Тут, кстати, интересно сравнить с Lombok-ом. Мы можем написать класс, указав над ним аннотацию `@Getter`, создать его класс-наследник и в нём обращаться по `super` к геттерам родительского класса. Хотя они, как и в случае с рекордом, точно так же очевидно отсутствуют на этапе компиляции. Но ошибок и предупреждений нет.

Comment: Почему "отсутствуют"?  Ломбок сгенерирует соответствующие методы и они _уже будут доступны_ на этапе компиляции, хотя они не будут прописаны в исходном коде.

Comment: И аналогия с ломбоком не совсем применима, так как кортежи не позволяют создавать иерархии классов _вообще_.

Comment: Ааа, точно, он же сразу код генерирует. Да, согласен) Насчёт аналогии - ну да, тоже верно. Но сами кортежи всё равно наследуются от `Record`, поэтому мне как-то и пришёл в голову пример с Lombok-ом и наследованием

Comment: `Record` оказался супер-абстрактным, я даже как-то не обращал внимания, что там и методы `Object` обязаны быть переопределены. :)

Comment: А почему `test.str2()` работает корректно, если геттеров еще нет?

Comment: Геттеры для компонентов кортежа создаются по умолчанию "сразу же" при объявлении типа кортежа.  А _явное переопределение_ этих геттеров -- как правило, совершенно лишнее и бесполезное занятие.